# How to get constructor parameters in __setattr__ function?

Tags: inheritance, python-3.x, constructor

I have a class:

```
class CustomDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self, wrong_keys, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDictionary, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
        self.wk = wrong_keys
        print(self.wk)

    ########### other methods

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print(self.wk) # error

        key = key.replace(" ", "_")
        self.__dict__[key] = value
```

And I have the client of this class:

```
def main():
    wrong_keys = ["r23", "fwfew", "s43t"]

    dictionary = CustomDictionary(wrong_keys)
    dictionary.aws = 5
```

I have the error on the line `print(self.wk)`: `KeyError: 'wk'`. On the other hand, the line `print(self.wk)` successfully print my `tuple`.

What mistake I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the trackback you neglected to post.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programs\python34\tem.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\programs\python34\tem.py", line 17, in main
    dictionary = CustomDictionary(wrong_keys)
  File "c:\programs\python34\tem.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.__dict__ = self  #<<< calls __setattr__ before self.wk is set
  File "c:\programs\python34\tem.py", line 9, in __setattr__
    print(self.wk) # error  #<<< calls __setattr__ before self.wk is set
AttributeError: 'CustomDictionary' object has no attribute 'wk'
```

The immediate solution is to replace the debug print in `.__setattr__` with

```
try:
    print(self.wk) # error
except: pass
```

I am not sure is `self.__dict__ = self` is ready needed or if it will work, but with this change, the code runs and you can continue.